# Jquery resizable plugin, alsoResize option issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-resizable

When handles: 'all' option, i get a problem.
The resizing of the second element always occurs so that the top left corner of that element stays in the same place.

What if I drag the top left corner of the first element? Then I get this: http://jsfiddle.net/gcDYq/embedded/result/

For some reason the element resizing with the element you are resizing is relative to the top left corner. That logic is thus causing this problem.

How do I fix this?

I hope this is clear enough on what the problem is and you guys can help me out :)

Comment: didn't quite get you: what do you want to happen or what you don't?

Comment: well for example, try resizing the left edge. You notice that the element that is also being resized is resizing it's right edge (in other words it is not following the parent element). I want it to do that.

Answer (score 0):

take a look at this modification: http://jsfiddle.net/gcDYq/19/ - as i see it's not the point of jqueryUI resise function, but visual html-element positioning - if you change also's CSS to *#also {float:right;}​* you'll se another picture